# What is the difference between MaxPermSize and MaxPermGen in Jboss configuration?

Tags: jboss, permgen

There are two attributes that I figured out. I guess some of the Jboss versions support `MaxPermGen` and some other versions support `MaxPermSize`.

Thats my guess only. What is the exact difference between those two attributes ?

I tried to replace `MaxPermGen` with `MaxPermSize` in my Jboss 5.1.0 to findout the difference. JBoss failed to start.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not aware of any `MaxPermGen` option of the Sun VM (in any version of the JVM) and invalid options will prevent the JVM to start properly.

However, `MaxPermSize` is correct and allows to define the *Size of the Permanent Generation*.

#### Reference

- [A Collection of JVM Options](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tech/vmoptions-jsp-140102.html) (most exhaustive resource I know)

Comment: Updated link http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tech/vmoptions-jsp-140102.html